# Covert JSX element to string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get the double quotes instead of &quot ; in the string?

```
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from "react-dom/server";

export default function App() {
  var a = (
    <>
      {`Code "Sand" box.`} <br /> {`CodeSandbox`}
    </>
  );
  var b = renderToStaticMarkup(a);
  var c = (b.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + b.slice(1)).slice(0, 20) + "...";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{c}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-nobel-8mwzu5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Why are you putting that information in curly braces and template strings? Just do `Code "Sand" box.<br />CodeSandbox`, and remove `b` and `c` - I'm not sure what they do - but you could probably use classes.

Comment: See, that codeSandbox is a small version of the problem which I'm facing in a project. I have data arranged in an array of objects. `a` is a property in an object that's why I'm using curly braces and template strings to put the <br> tag in the value. I now want to get just the text from it so that I can apply methods to it.